# GitLab update changes /etc/passwd

Tags: gitlab

Debian 9

I install GitLab just `aptitude install gitlab-ce`

During install was created user `git` (and group `git`).
New line in `/etc/passwd`:

`git:x:777:777::/var/opt/gitlab:/bin/sh`

I changed shell for this user to `/bin/bash`.
And add a few users to the group `git` (it changed files `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`).

But when I update the system (`aptitude safe-upgrade`) and exist updates for GitLab it resets all three files: `passwd`, `group`, `gshadow`.
It removes other users from git-group and reset shell.

I am sad.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply treat the `git` user and group  as reserved for gitlab's internal use. If you wish to create a group for your shell users, name it something else.

See [the Gitlab documentation on this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/configuration.md#changing-the-name-of-the-git-user-group) for renaming the group that Gitlab uses otherwise.